# What does the bias of the jackknife method mean?

Tags: bias, jackknife

If we apply the jackknife method on a dataset and estimate a bias, what does that mean in physical interpretation? I mean without using statistical words how can I can interpret the results?

Comment: For clarification, when you say __bias__ are you referring to the statistical bias that is a measure of the difference between a statistic's expected value and the parameter's true value? If so, what are you estimating the bias of?

Comment: Hard to answer without more detail. Do you understand what the word _bias_ means in English outside statistics?

Comment: @mdewey how far we are from the actual results? I think..

Comment: Please do not repeatedly post your question--and visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge your accounts.